# ¿Como enviar el valor del DOM de un formulario sin actualizar la pagina con js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Soy nueva en el mundo de programación con JavaScript.... quisiera saber alguna idea que pueda ayudarme a resolver mi problema (el formulario deberá enviarse cada 15 segundos pero sin actualizar la pagina). Esta es la forma en que lo estoy haciendo, uso el evento prevent default pero aun asi se actualiza la pagina, si uso el $("#form").submit(function(event) no se actualiza la pagina pero no se envia el valor del formulario. Este es mi codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
(function() {
    var print = function(){
    let formulario = document.getElementById('form');
    formulario.submit(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    };
   setInterval(print,15000);
}())
```

});

Comment: ¿Y ese valor del formulario a dónde se debe de mandar?

Comment: Si haces un submit y luego un preventDefault como que se contradicen.
Deberias de usar Ajax para envios de un formulario. Puedo enviarte un ejemplo a modo de prueba. Que lenguaje usas del lado servidor? Podrias facilitar el tipo de formulario de datos? y porque enviar cada 15 segundos? No estarias duplicando los envios de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que estabas utilizando `preventDefault` en la función callback del método `submit` de jQuery y no estabas "escuchando" el evento en sí, de ahí lo de `formulario.on("submit", ...)`. He he ajustado un poco el código para que funcione y, ya que usas jQuery, usarlo al 100%.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const formulario = $('#form');

    (function() {
        var print = function(){
            formulario.on("submit", function(event) { 
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            formulario.submit();
        };
        setInterval(print,3000);
    }())
});
```

Te he dejado [una demo aquí](https://repl.it/@juanwmedia/jQuery-sandbox) para que veas que no recarga la página.

Saludos!.